# How to reference individual element of funtion that returns table type in oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have created a function which return table type i.e two column values.I want to use these individual columns while inserting into other table via select statement.

```
create or replace type emp_sal as object(empno number,sal number);

create or replace nt_emp_sal is table of emp_sal;

create or replace function emp_fun(deptno number) 
return nt_emp_sal 
is
  l_nt_emp_sal nt_emp_sal := nt_emp_sal();
begin
  select emp_sal(empno,sal) bulk collect 
    into l_nt_emp_sal 
    from emp where deptno=p_deptno;
  return l_nt_emp_sal;
end;
```

Comment: Here is my code:First i have created object type,then nested table type used this nested table type in function return. 
create or replace type emp_sal as object(empno number,sal number);
create or replace nt_emp_sal is table of emp_sal;
create or replace function emp_fun(deptno number) return nt_emp_sal 
is 
l_nt_emp_sal nt_emp_sal := nt_emp_sal(); 
begin 
select emp_sal(empno,sal) bulk collect into l_nt_emp_sal from emp where deptno=p_deptno; 
return l_nt_emp_sal;
end;

Comment: Please do not use comments to provide additional details. Instead, edit your question. I've done it for you. Feel free to review those changes and/or edit your question further if needed.

Answer (score 0):

You basically need to use the `TABLE()` keyword in your query around the function call to use the result just like any other table. Given your sample code, you will write something like :

```
INSERT INTO ... (colA, colB)
SELECT * FROM TABLE(emp_fun(123))
--            ^^^^^^            ^
```

From the doc [*"Using Pipelined and Parallel Table Functions"*](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14289/dcitblfns.htm#sthref651):

> Table functions return a collection type instance and can be queried like a table by calling the function in the FROM clause of a query. Table functions use the TABLE keyword.

---

You can find a detailed example at http://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/pipelined-table-functions.php :

```
CREATE TYPE t_tf_row AS OBJECT (
  id           NUMBER,
  description  VARCHAR2(50)
);
/

CREATE TYPE t_tf_tab IS TABLE OF t_tf_row;
/

-- Build the table function itself.
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_tab_tf (p_rows IN NUMBER) 
RETURN t_tf_tab 
AS
  l_tab  t_tf_tab := t_tf_tab();
BEGIN
   -- func def here
   -- ...
END;
/
```

And here is the relevant part:

```
SELECT *
FROM   TABLE(get_tab_tf(10))
--     ^^^^^^           ^
ORDER BY id DESC
```

Comment: Thanks Sylvain for quick reply

Comment: @Rajus Glad to have helped you. If you find this helpful, feel free to [vote up and/or accept the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). This is the primarily way to say "thank you" here on StackOverflow.